# eosd missing after build

Tags: testnet

I'm following along on the github tutorials for dawn-2.x public and private testnet nodes. After running `./build.sh` I move onto the next step and try to start the eos daemon `cd ~/eos/build/scripts; ./start_npnode.sh`, but receive the following error in stderr.txt.

`../programs/eosd/eosd: No such file or directory`

I've tried the build process on both mac and ubuntu several times with fresh installations, but keep coming back to this same issue.

Answer (score 4):

First of all 2.x is really old now.  As of this writing you're better off with dawn 4.1.

But you might have missed make install before trying to run your node.

```
cd build
sudo make install
```